# Differentiability of first derivative of a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, derivatives, continuity

If a function $f$ is differentiable on domain $D$ and $f'$ is increasing on $D$, is $f'$ necessarily continuous on $D$? Is $f'$ necessarily differentiable on $D$? Counterexamples? 
From Darboux theorem we know $f'$ can't have jump discontinuities.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_classes answers your first question.

Comment: I'm unclear on your 2nd question, didn't you already assume $f$ is diff'tiable?

Comment: sorry I mean if $f'$ has to be differentiable

Answer (score 1):

What kind discontinuities can a derivative have? (you answered that already in your question). Can an increasing function have discontinuities other than jump discontinuities? Combine both answers to conclude that if $f'$ is increasing on $D$, then it is continuous on $D$.

If you meant to ask whether $f'$ has to be differentiable, then the answer is no. Take any continuous a non-differentiable function $g$. Use the fundamental theorem of calculus to construct a function $f$ with $f'=g$. Choose $g$ increasing if you wish $f'$ increasing too.